# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, socket, client-server

I'm facing an error on running the node script which generates the PayPal invoices using SDK and when it runs from the local server it is working fine but when it runs on production server it is giving below error:

```
Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
    "code": "ECONNRESET",
    "path": null,
    "host": "api.paypal.com",
    "port": 443,
    "stack": [
        "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
        "    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1095:19)",
        "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)",
        "    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
    ]
}
```

**Version Details:**

> Node Js 10.x, TLS: 1.0

Did anybody face such errors?